# What is recursieve md-list tags hierarchy and use of list-item ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I have two questions about my recursively created list with expandable items/nodes.

Main nodes displayed by:

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item ng-repeat="section in menu" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-include="'section.html'"></md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

child and all in next levels are displayed by:

```
<md-item-content md-ink-ripple layout="row" ng-click="openSection(section); $event.stopPropagation()" ng-hide="false" ng-disabled="true">
    <div class="inset" ng-bind="section.title">
    </div>
</md-item-content>
<md-list>
    <md-list-item ng-if="section.childrenMenuItem" ng-repeat="section in section.childrenMenuItem" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-include="'section.html'"></md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

1.This generates clickable list item `md-ink-ripple` effect and when I use ng-disable that effect is not displayed again but action on `openSection` starts and section is opened. Is there way to block action on click besides check inside function if item is disabled?

2.When I change hierarchy of list in child nodes from md-item-content to somthing else in few cases `md-ink-ripple` is displayed on whole list on all elements or few elements in the same time but recursively deeper. What is the proper hierarchy of `md-list` created this way?